# Get the content of an HTML input in a bean without using passthrough atts

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm using a javascript that transforms a textArea in an editor (primefaces editor wasn't costumizable enough).

So I've this code:

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1"  rows="10" cols="80" >
</textarea>  

    <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1');
    </script>
```

I would like to get the content of the text area in a managed bean.
I didn't manage to make it work with the jsf tags for inputTextarea.

### EDIT: I guess it's not working because the id isn't the same when using

```
<h:inputTextarea id="editor1"/>
```

this will result in an id like :

> j_tid53:editor1

I also tried this :

```
xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
...
jsf:value="#{bean.property}"
```

but it will be `null`

### Edit:

my xhtml namespace:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

faces-config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

and when the server start in the console:

```
Initializing Mojarra 2.2.9 (-SNAPSHOT 20141218-0939 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.9@14083) for context
```

So how can I get the content of my textArea ?

Comment: no. the value is null.

Comment: Nvm I figured it out.

Comment: Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1). By the way my namespace in my html files are correct ? According to this: https://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/jsf22-namespaces/  the new namespace should start with: http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf. And for info  I made it work (see answer below) but I can't get the value of the textarea. I might have to make my own custom editor. I'll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script wasn't working because the id was wrong. I just had to give the form an id as such:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:inputTextarea value="#{newThread.title}" cols="98" rows="1">
        <f:passThroughAttribute name="placeholder" value="#{miscellaneous.Title}"/>
    </p:inputTextarea>

    <p:inputTextarea id="sup"></p:inputTextarea>   
        <script>

        CKEDITOR.replace( 'form:sup');
        </script>



    <p:commandButton value="#{miscellaneous.Submit}" action="#{newThread.sendNewThread}">
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

The problem is that I didn't know how to get the value. So I switched to the [primeface extension](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/ckEditor.jsf).

Those are the dependencies needed:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

then the namespace in the xhtml file:

```
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
```

and [here is a link that explains step by step.](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/wiki/Getting-Started)

[If you are not using primefaces you can make it work by following the comment of w vd L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697310/using-ckeditor-in-jsf-page/30705553#30705553)