# Primefaces-extensions ckeditor - missing toolbar

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, primefaces-extensions

I am trying to use the primefaces-extensions `ckEditor` in my JSF application, as described [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/customToolbar.jsf). I added the dependency to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is how my view looks like:

```
<p:growl id="editorgrowl" showDetail="true" />
<pe:ckEditor id="editor" value="#{mbEditorController.content}"
    toolbar="[['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt']]">
    <p:ajax event="save"
        listener="#{mbEditorController.saveListener}"
        update="editorgrowl" />
</pe:ckEditor>
```

This is the controller (managed bean):

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mbEditorController")
@ViewScoped
public class EditorView implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6822767317343704211L;

    private String content;

    private String secondContent;

    public EditorView() {
        content = "Type in your text here...";
        secondContent = "This is a second editor";
    }

    public void saveListener() {
        content = content.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
        final FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Content",
                content.length() > 150 ? content.substring(0, 100) : content);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public void secondSaveListener() {
        secondContent = secondContent.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
        final FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Second Content",
                secondContent.length() > 150 ? secondContent.substring(0, 100) : secondContent);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    // getters, setters
}
```

Unfortunately I can't see a toolbar, but just a text input area, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image: Missing toolbar in ckEditor]

**UPDATE**

There is a javascript error in my console:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/ckeditor.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=4.0.0 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

What could cause the problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you see any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: @tak3shi: Yes! Sorry, I should have do it before posting. But I still don't know, why it happens. Can you help? Updated my post.

Comment: Another hint can be found in your server log: `Unable to find or serve resource, ckeditor/ckeditor.js, from library, primefaces-extensions.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ckeditor in jsf page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697310/using-ckeditor-in-jsf-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much tak3shi! I was missing this.

Comment: Why oh why isn't this the first line in the showcase!? For 6.0.0 this is also required.