# PrimeFaces Extensions CKEditor: attempts to set encoding to UTF-8 unsuccessful

Tags: jsf, primefaces, character-encoding, ckeditor, primefaces-extensions

### Why I am using this editor:

In the past I used PrimeFaces [`p:editor`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/editor.xhtml) which is however deprecated and lacks functions that the users desperately want. I cannot use the new PrimeFaces [`p:textEditor`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/textEditor.xhtml) because of this: [Primefaces textEditor: converting text to HTML with JavaScript not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395378/primefaces-texteditor-converting-text-to-html-with-javascript-not-working).

### What is it used for:

I am using [`pe:ckEditor`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/basicUsage.jsf) from PrimeFaces Extensions in my program, in which the editor is used by the user to create an e-mail message content. Then by click on a send button, the HTML from the editor is taken and sent via e-mail to a client.

### What is the issue:

When using `p:editor`, I got the HTML by JavaScript function `saveHTML` and it worked perfectly even when the text contained Czech characters (ěščřžýáíéó), I did not even have to set enconding or anything else and it worked.
Now however when user writes *"V případě dalších dotazů se na nás můžete obracet každý den na telefonním čísle"*, the gotten HTML has the text like this:*"V pÅípadÄ dalších dotazÅ¯ se na nás mÅ¯Å¾ete obracet kaÅ¾dý den na telefonním Äísle"* - complete rubbish that the user obviously cannot send to a client...

### My research:

EDIT: Based on some comments, I tried to add the `<meta charset="utf-8>` and `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` but that did not help. In `pom.xml` I have found also this `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`, so I do not think that there is a problem in the HTML page, but in settings of the editor itself...

So I figured, that the encoding must be set especially for the editor in its config. I finally figured [how to make the editor access the custom config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59612256/primefaces-extensions-ckeditor-cannot-access-custom-config), but **nothing that I found on the Internet and added to the config worked for me:**

```
config.language='cs';
```

And:

```
config.entities_latin = false;
```

And:

```
config.entities = false;
```

And:

```
config.basicEntities = false;
```

And all its combinations.

ANOTHER EDIT:

Based on some other comments here, I also installed OmniFaces and tried to solve this by [`CharacterEncodingFilter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/CharacterEncodingFilter), but nothing changed and it is still not working.

I also found out that my problem seems to be very related to this issue: [Unicode input retrieved via PrimeFaces input components become corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634230/unicode-input-retrieved-via-primefaces-input-components-become-corrupted), but the accepted answer there gives 3 ways how to solve it, one is the `CharacterEncodingFilter`, other way is not applicable for Tomcat users (me) and the last "solution" seems to be reporting this to PrimeFaces Extensions developers (which I did: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/756 ).

**Please let me know if you know how to fix this or if there is any workaround.**

---

PrimeFaces Extensions - version 7.0.2;
PrimeFaces - version 7.0.7

Comment: This is called _mojibake_ and the solution is to ensure the charset is UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: @MrLister How can I ensure that the charset is everywhere? To where should I add it and in what form?

Comment: It's not easy giving specific pieces of advice, since you have not included any code in your question, but you can start by checking the charset of the entire page.

Comment: I have not included any code because the project is very complex and there are many html files inside html files inside html files etc (so I think it would make the question rather unclear). But I will look into this matter, thank you for advice @MrLister.

Comment: @MrLister I edited the whole question based on what I tried and what the issue is now.

Comment: @A.Alessio have you tried to set the Character Encoding. We use the OmniFaces CharacterEncodingFilter to set ours to UTF-8.  http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/CharacterEncodingFilter  Its a simple servlet filter you could copy the code if you don't want to bring in OmniFaces.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Melloware, I'll look into to it!

Comment: You **should** bring in omnifaces (for more than one reason ;-))

Comment: @Melloware I added the code from the page you provided `<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>` to the `web.xml` but then errors appear in the console and the website won't even load. Is it sufficient to put the code into the xml file (from what I understood, it should be) or should I do anything else? Thank you for help and any suggestions.

Comment: That should be all you have to do?

Comment: @Melloware from what I understood from the page, yes; then I thought that I cannot use OmniFaces feature without having installed the OmniFaces, but then again I recalled a part of your comment saying _"Its a simple servlet filter you could copy the code if you don't want to bring in OmniFaces."_ , so now I am confused... Do I need to have the whole OmniFaces installed to use the feature or not? Thanks in advance, because this is my first time with OmniFaces and I am not successful at googling what to do with it and how to use it...

Comment: @Melloware I installed OmniFaces and used the `CharacterEncodingFilter` according to the guide on the page, but nothing has changed, it is still not working. Do you (or anybody) have any other ideas how to fix it? From what I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634230/unicode-input-retrieved-via-primefaces-input-components-become-corrupted), my only other solution seems to be reporting the bug directly to the PrimeFaces Extensions developers...

Comment: Yes I meant you could copy the omniFaces source code if you didn't want to include the JAR.  But i see you got that resolved.  As far as reporting it to PFE yes you can report it here: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues

Comment: Thanks, @Melloware for your time and help. It really seems that reporting it to the developers is the only solution left...

Comment: I reported it as a bug: (https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/756)[https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/756].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I and my colleague found out what the issue was based on the [test code that @melloware provided](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/756). 
The original editor `p:editor`, which we had been using and which we are trying to replace by `pe:ckEditor`, could provide us with its content in HTML only in case we used JavaScript function `saveHTML`.
But with `pe:ckEditor`, anytime the user hit the *Send* button, whose `onstart` contained the `saveHTML`, **the `saveHTML` corrupted the content. Once we erased the `saveHTML`** and took the `pe:ckEditor` content as it was (which is already in HTML), **it was fine without corrupted characters.**