# How to enable browser spellcheck in pe:ckEditor

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ckeditor, spell-checking, primefaces-extensions

[`pe:ckEditor`](http://[![enter%20image%20description%20here][2]][2]) is used in my program by a user to enter new e-mail message content. Users need browser spellcheck enabled.

I know that the *ckEditor*, on which the `pe:ckEditor` is based, can have this enabled by adding [`config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/spellcheck.html) to config, however `pe:ckEditor` does not have a config file and is modified by values of its attributes. Though, I have not found in its doc any attribute that would achieve this.

I checked similar questions here, but vast majority of them is about *ckEditor* and modifying its config, which is useless for this case.

Please, let me know if you know a solution to this issue.

---

[image: pe:ckEditor showcase - not enabled browser spellcheck apparent]
[image: apparent enabled browser spellcheck]

Comment: I htink it is similar to this ticket: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/740  I think the plugin has to be added to the core component I don't think there is an easy way to plug components in from the outside based on the way JSF/PFE has the load the plugins.

Comment: Feel free to submit a PR adding the Spell Check plugin to PFE!

Comment: Hi, @Melloware. Thank you for your comment. From what I understood from the *ckEditor* docs, it is not necessary to add any plugin to enable browser spellcheck, just to add  `config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;` to its config file - the doc says *"By default, native browser spell check functionality is disabled in the editor. Use the config.disableNativeSpellChecker configuration option to enable it"*. Using config file is not an option for me. `pe:ckEditor` has no attributes that would modify this behaviour. Is plugin really necessary? Or am I missing smth? Please let me know. Thank you

Comment: See my solution below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried defining your own custom config JS file like..

```js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
};
```

And then calling the PFE customConfig option like...

```xml
<pe:ckEditor id="editor" 
             value="#{editorController.content}"
             customConfig="#{request.contextPath}/js/config/myconfig.js" />
```

Or as of PFE 8.0.1 there is a new attribute "disableNativeSpellChecker='false'" you can set on the pe:ckeditor itself

https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/763

Comment: I have figured out how to access custom config in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59612256/primefaces-extensions-ckeditor-cannot-access-custom-config. However that is an inelegant workaround for me, because I would have to move all (many)  files containing `pe:ckEditor` to a folder that is accessible via URL + I would have to make a special method generating the URL as have more environments (dev, test, prod, etc.), so the URL varies on each environment.

Comment: Is it the only way? If so, can I submit a ticket somewhere with a suggestion for making an attribute, whose value would modify this?

Comment: I don't understand.  Just put this one config.js in your webapp and reference it from #{request.contextPath}/js/config/myconfig.js   that is just 1 file?  I don't know what you mean you would have to make the folder accessible via URL?

Comment: Or open a ticket here for us to make this a default: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues

Comment: Thank you, I will do that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the previous answer from @Melloware, I reported an issue. Based on it **a new attribute to modify this behaviour has been made**. See https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/763.